# How to change add-to-cart form?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to change the WooCommerce add-to-cart form through functions.php?

The goal is to add a checkbox for an additional product. When the checkbox is checked this product will also be added to the cart after a click on the add to cart button.

I am looking for a solution which doesn't rely on javascript.

Comment: Yes, you can either override the `add-to-cart` template entirely in your theme... though I think this is risky and ill-advised. Or, you can use the [`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php#L43) and [`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php#L59) to add your new input to the add to cart form.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately those two hooks will add the new html before and after the <form>, but not into the form. Right now I am leaning towards overriding the template /woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

Comment: No they don't. before and after the *button* is still within the `<form>`. Check again in the source lines I linked you to. `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form` and `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form` are outside of the `<form>` and are maybe what you are thinking of.

Comment: Oh yes, you are absolutely right! Thanks!!

Comment: helgatheviking. Would you also know how to format an additional <input> field so that the value is also passed to the cart? I'd like to add an additional product to the cart when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: That's kind of a different question. Woo has 2 plugins that almost do that, but I'm not sure they have the optional checkbox feature you describe.

Comment: That's why I'm researching how to do it myself (with help of you and others :)

Comment: If you take a stab and open up a new question I will probably take a look when it isn't so far past my bedtime. Two tips, you'll need the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook, **but** calling `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` on this hook causes a whole bunch of problems thanks for recursion or looping or something, so you are better off adding the item directly into the `WC()->cart->cart_contents` array.

Comment: I'd rather keep it in the same thread as this is part of the initial question, or what do you think? Thanks for the advice on the 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' hook. I will look into that.

Comment: You're right it was in the original question. My brain got fried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better title would be **"WooCommerce up-sells as checkboxes"**.

A lot of research and several strategies to tackle this problem lead me to a solution which I thought was not even possible in the beginning.

The solution is now exactly what I wanted. A non-JavaScript, no-template-override, but a simple and pure addition to functions.php. It works for simple and variable products (and probably with grouped and external products too).

It misses some nice features still. It won't work yet if an up-sell is a variable product. Quantity selection and limiting up-sells per item or order would be nice additions too. Based on the code below adding those features should not be a big deal anymore.

```
// create the checkbox form fields and add them before the cart button
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0 );
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form(){
    global $woocommerce, $product;

    // get the product up-sells
    $upsells = $product->get_upsells();

    // store the number of up-sells and pass it on to the add-to-cart hook
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="upsells_size" value="<?php echo(sizeof($upsells)); ?>">
    <div id="wb-upsell-div">
    <?php

    // iterate through all upsells and add an input field for each
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $upsells as $value ){
        $product_id  = $value;
        ?>
        <input id="wb-upsell-checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="upsell_<?php echo($i) ?>" value="<?php echo($product_id); ?>"><?php echo( '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $product_id )) . '" target="_blank">' . get_the_title( $product_id ) . "</a>". "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;($" . get_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', true) . ")"); ?><br>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>  
    </div>
    <?php
}


// function to add all up-sells, where the checkbox have been checked, to the cart 
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 3);
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // get the number of up-sells to iterate through
    $upsell_size = $_POST['upsells_size'];

    // iterate through up-sell fields
    for ($i=1; $i<=$upsell_size; $i++){

        // get the product id of the up-sell
        $product_id = $_POST['upsell_' . $i];

        $found = false;

        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the CSS for formatting the `<div>`and the checkboxes. It goes into the style.css file:

```
#wb-upsell-div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#wb-upsell-checkboxes{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's an actual answer to this question, you can add whatever you want inside the add to cart `<form>` using hooks. For example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'so_34115452_add_input' );
function so_34115452_add_input(){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="something"/>' . __( 'Some Checkbox', 'text-domain' );
}
```