# Problems with upsell products from the product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The code below adds checkboxes with up-sell products to the product page. The code displays the image of the product, allows choosing the quantity, hides the products without stock and which do not allow pre-orders. So far, everything works perfectly. Problems arise in the case of products without stock and which allow pre-orders.

1. Out-of-stock products that allow pre-orders that have "Allow, but notify customer" checked are not displayed on the product page.
2. Out-of-stock products that allow pre-orders that have "Allow" checked are displayed on the product page, but cannot be added to the cart. There is no error when adding the product to the cart, the main product is added to the cart without any problems.If several products are checked, all products with stock are added to the cart, only the one without stock is not added to the cart.

How to solve these problems (or at least the one from point 2)?

```
// Adding upsell products to the cart by checking a box and selecting the quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0 );
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form(){
    global $product;

    // Get the product up-sells
    $upsells = $product->get_upsells();

    // Store the number of up-sells and pass it on to the add-to-cart hook
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="upsells_size" value="<?php echo sizeof( $upsells ); ?>">
    <div id="wb-upsell-div" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <?php

    // Iterate through all upsells and add an input field for each
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $upsells as $value ){
        $product_id  = $value;
        $product_obj = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // Check if the product allows backorders (preorders) or has stock
        $backorders_allowed = $product_obj->get_backorders();
        $stock_status = $product_obj->get_stock_status();
        $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();

        // Add product to cart if it allows backorders or is in stock, even if stock quantity is null
        if ( $stock_status === 'instock' || ( $backorders_allowed === 'yes' && $backorders_allowed !== 'notify' ) || ( $stock_status === 'outofstock' && $backorders_allowed === 'yes' ) ) {
            ?>
            <label for="upsell_<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-right: 20px;">
                <input id="wb-upsell-checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="upsell_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $product_obj->get_image_id(), array( 25, 25 ) ); ?>
                <?php echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $product_id ) ) . '" target="_blank">' . get_the_title( $product_id ) . "</a>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(" . get_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', true ) . " euro)"; ?>
                <span style="margin-left: 10px;"></span>
                <input type="number" name="upsell_quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" min="1" value="1" max="<?php echo $product_obj->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ? $product_obj->get_stock_quantity() : ''; ?>">
            </label>
            <?php
            $i++;
        }
    }
    ?>  
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Function to add all up-sells, where the checkbox has been checked, to the cart 
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 3);
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    // Get the number of up-sells to iterate through
    $upsell_size = $_POST['upsells_size'];

    // Iterate through up-sell fields
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $upsell_size; $i++){

        // Get the product id of the up-sell
        $product_id = $_POST['upsell_' . $i];

        // Get the quantity selected for the up-sell
        $quantity = isset($_POST['upsell_quantity_' . $i]) ? absint($_POST['upsell_quantity_' . $i]) : 1;

        $found = false;

        // Check if the product is already in the cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id ) {
                    $found = true;

                    // Get the available stock quantity for the product
                    $available_stock = $_product->get_stock_quantity();

                    // Adjust quantity if it exceeds available stock
                    if ( $available_stock !== null && $quantity > $available_stock ) {
                        $quantity = $available_stock;
                    }

                    // Update the quantity if the product is already in the cart
                    WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity, true );
                }
            }
            // If the product is not found, add it to the cart
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
        } else {
            // If no products are in the cart, add the product to the cart
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to deactivate the stock check, but in this case, the products without stock that do not allow pre-order are also displayed on the product page. Besides that, if you tick a product without stock and which does not allow pre-orders, adding the product to the basket is not functional.

The code is based on the answer here [How to change add-to-cart form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115452/how-to-change-add-to-cart-form/34134486#34134486).

P.S: I used Google Translate for the text (I hope you understand what I wanted to say in my post).

Comment: _"I tried to deactivate the stock check, but in this case, the products without stock that do not allow pre-order are also displayed on the product page."_ - so you must be talking about the check inside `action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`, which decides which products will be shown in the first place. I don't see how that would affect what is happening inside `custom_add_to_cart` then ...? Have you debugged the latter function, to see if those products without stock "arrive" in there in the first place?

Comment: `( $backorders_allowed === 'yes' && $backorders_allowed !== 'notify' )` - that second condition is superfluous. If `$backorders_allowed` _does_ have the value `yes`, then that automatically means it _can not_ have the value `notify`.

Comment: Your current logic checks whether a product is in stock or allows backorders but doesn't fully account for all backorder settings (like 'Allow, but notify customer'). You need to refine these checks to handle all scenarios properly.